# Copy file to a directory using python

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to copy **some_file** to another **directory** (say c:).

Here is my code:

```
import os
filetest = 'c:\\Documents and Settings\\secret\\Desktop\\testToCopy.txt'
tempdir = 'c:\\'
os.system('copy %s %s' % (filetest, tempdir))
```

But for some strange reason I always get this answer in response:

**The system cannot find the file specified.**

Comment: I suggest removing that `os` call and using `shutil.copy(src, dst)` instead. You'll need a `import shutil`. [Doc link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy)

Comment: Usually arguments containing spaces must be double-quoted. Anyway, you should use shutil interface as suggested by @pie3636

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments, you should quote the `copy` arguments as they may [and in this case do] contain spaces:

```
os.system('copy "%s" "%s"' % (filetest, tempdir))
```

As pointed by @pie3636, you should consider using the `shutil.copy` for that purpose.